# Sequence in R Program

Tags: r

Lets say that I want a vector of multiplication of 10k, but it starts with number 1. Ex: (1, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, ...) How do I create this kind of vector? The difference of (10000 - 1) = 9999, while the difference of other values is 10000.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `seq`

```
options(scipen=999)
c(1,seq(10000, length.out=10, by = 10000))
#[1]      1  10000  20000  30000  40000  50000  60000  70000  80000  90000
#[11] 100000
```

Change the `length.out` to whatever the `...` means.

Answer (score 0):

*Generate Sequence*

```
x <- seq(10000,100000,by=10000)

> is.vector(x)
[1] TRUE

> first = c(1)
> final = c(first,x)
> str(final)
  num [1:11] 1 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 60000 70000 80000 90000 ...
```

Is this what you are looking for?